# setting vue to production laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, production

I am getting a message on my site "You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production."

I tried turning on production mode by changing my "package.js" to this however I am still getting the message. I also changed my .env to `APP ENV= production`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run production",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove that warning, run this before deploying to production:

```
npm run production
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build your assets thanks to Laravel Mix, don't forget to build them after changing your `APP_ENV` => `npm run prod`

Comment: I have this in my laravel mix webpackconfig.js     vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'

Answer (score 0):

In Vuejs, if you run your app with `npm run serve` you will be in development mode and with `npm run build` in production mode. 
I also had this message but it did not create any conflict with the production

Comment: 1st you have to define build key value on scripts object in package.json. the answer is diffrent from above question